# building geeqie on arch: ninja error undefined reference to lua_settop

Tags: compiling, ld

I am trying to build geeqie from https://github.com/BestImageViewer/geeqie.git.

Following instructions in the README.md

```
`meson setup build`  
`ninja -C build install`
```

The meson runs without error but the ninja quits on this :

```
usr/bin/ld: src/geeqie.p/lua.cc.o: in function `luaL_typerror(lua_State*, int, char const*)':
/hd2/projects/external/geeqie/build/../src/lua.cc:61: undefined reference to `luaL_argerror(lua_State*, int, char const*)'
/usr/bin/ld: src/geeqie.p/lua.cc.o: in function `lua_init()':
/hd2/projects/external/geeqie/build/../src/lua.cc:353: undefined reference to `lua_settop(lua_State*, int)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

I'm have little experience with building from source so I suspect this is my error somewhere.

Comment: Which platform is this on?

Comment: @MarcusMüller Arch up to date with 6.02 kernel. Is that what you're looking for?